# gpu branch serialization versus predication

Tags: serialization, branch, gpu

Consider the following GPU kernel code:

```
if (p)
  A
else
  B
```

Suppose that this branch causes warp divergence.  I have read in numerous documents (e.g., [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#control-flow-instructions)) that such branches are handled either by serializing the two branches or by branch predication, with the choice of which scheme to use typically depending on the size of the branches.

My question is: Aren't those two schemes *effectively* the same? With serialization, first the A block is executed on the A-threads while the B-threads stall, then the B block is executed on the B-threads while the A-threads stall; with predication, first the A block is executed on all threads but actually executed on only the A-threads, then the B block is executed on all threads but actually executed on only the B-threads.

In both schemes, we have the A-threads (actually) executing the A block, followed by the B-threads (actually) executing the B block.  The implementation details differ, obviously, but the essential behavior and performance are, as far as I understand, effectively the same.

Am I correct, or is there some difference between serialization and predication that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Branch predication has its advantages when the number of instructions in A and B are small. This is a general computer architecture concept that has been around for several years. For example, look at the advantages listed in the Wikipedia article:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(computer_architecture)

With predication the overall time is expected to be lesser.